# Get list of prompts and conversations for all ChatGPT sessions

Tags: web-scraping, openai-api

I have hundreds of ChatGPT conversations and I want to extract them all into a JSON structure.

- Name of conversation
- List of prompts and response for conversation.

I couldn't find anything in the [API Reference](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/) so wondering I have just missed or if there is a way I could do this using scraping.

```json
{
  "title": "Escape smoke, move stuff.",
  "prompts": [
    {
      "prompt": "Looking for suggestions! Due to the smoke season, I need to leave town for a few weeks but still want to maintain my current lifestyle. I want to bring my large monitor, chair, and other items with me. How far do I need to travel and which province(s) do you recommend for a good getaway? Also, any recommendations for transportation options like Grab, car, bus, or train?",
      "response": "I would recommend traveling to a province with cleaner air, such as British Columbia or Alberta. As for transportation, it really depends on your preference and budget. If you prefer comfort and convenience, renting a car might be the best option. If you're on a budget, taking a bus or train could be more affordable. However, if you want to save time, taking a Grab or driving your own car would be the most efficient. Just make sure to pack your items securely for the trip!"
    },
    {
      "prompt": "Imagine you are in the midst of a journey to escape the smoke season in your town. You have brought along your large monitor, chair, and other items to maintain your current lifestyle. As you travel, you wonder how far you need to go and which province(s) would be the best for a relaxing getaway. Consider different transportation options like Grab, car, bus, or train. Write about your experience and share your thoughts on the ideal destination for your escape.",
      "response": "As I left my town behind, I felt a sense of relief knowing that I would soon be breathing in cleaner air. I had packed my large monitor, chair, and other essentials to ensure that my escape would be as comfortable as possible. As I journeyed further, I wondered how far I needed to go to find a relaxing destination. I had heard that British Columbia and Alberta were good options, so I decided to head in that direction. Along the way, I considered different transportation options. While renting a car seemed like the most convenient option, I opted for a bus to save on costs. Finally, after a few hours of traveling, I arrived at my destination feeling rejuvenated and ready to enjoy my temporary escape from the smoke."
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

OpenAI terms and conditions prohibit web scraping. Related:

[Is it against ToS to scrape a conversation with ChatGPT?](https://community.openai.com/t/is-it-against-tos-to-scrape-a-conversation-with-chatgpt/74678)

From [comment](https://community.openai.com/t/is-it-against-tos-to-scrape-a-conversation-with-chatgpt/74678/2?u=rbn)

> Have a look at OpenAI’s [Terms of Use](https://openai.com/terms/). #2, section c, part iv:
>
> > You may not … use any method to extract data from the Services, including web scraping, web harvesting, or web data extraction methods, other than as permitted through the API;
>
> My interpretation is that scraping your ChatGPT conversations would go against the Terms of Services, UNLESS you have access to the [ChatGPT API](https://community.openai.com/t/chatgpt-api-waitlist-by-openai/39247) .

Anyway, might not be too hard to get your ChatGPT conversations using Chrome Developers Tools without having to impact the OpenAI infraestructure

1. Go to https://chat.openai.com/chat and login
2. Open Chrome Developer Tools
3. Open Application tab
4. Expand Frames > XHR and Fetch

Here you will see a list of files. From here you could get the link or even copy the file content.

AFAIK the Chat Completions end-point (marketed as ChatGPT API) doesn't provide access to the ChatGPT (https://chat.openai.com/chat) user data. It just give access to the Large Language Model that powers the ChatGPT web app.

Reference

- https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat
- https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat

Comment: thanks for this. I am super new to this and not aware about Developer tools. I checked but not sure how to do it. I just want to save my session instead of copy-pasting. Any tips?

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker Follow-up questions should be posted as new questions. P.S. I have updated my user profile. You should be able to see my website on the user card shown when you hover over my profile photo. I might improve my About me to add a summary that fits the user card later.